# getting error with execute many in python when i tried to connect to DB

Tags: python, database, csv

I am trying to use functions with mysql and python and I am getting errors:
I am reading a file cnn.cvs and I want to insert in a table noticias but I have errors in the code. Here I share the code:

```
import csv
import MySQLdb
mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
user='root',
passwd='password',
db='cnn')
cursor = mydb.cursor()
f = open('cnn.csv', 'r')
csv_data = csv.reader(f)
for row in csv_data:
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO noticias(title, \
link, pubDate )' \
'VALUES("%s", "%s", "%s")',
row)
#close the connection to the database.
mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
print ("Done")
```

and when i execute this is the result:

```
C:\Users\SoriyAntony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe 
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 
2017.1.4\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py" --multiproc --qt-support --client 127.0.0.1 --port 59726 --file C:/Users/SoriyAntony/PycharmProjects/cnnbd/cnnbd
pydev debugger: process 10368 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 171.4694.38)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\SoriyAntony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 238, in execute
query = query % args
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 
2017.1.4\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1591, in <module>
globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 
2017.1.4\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1018, in run
pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 
2017.1.4\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
File "C:/Users/SoriyAntony/PycharmProjects/cnnbd/cnnbd", line 17, in 
<module>
row)
File "C:\Users\SoriyAntony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 240, in execute
self.errorhandler(self, ProgrammingError, str(m))
File "C:\Users\SoriyAntony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\site-
packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 52, in defaulterrorhandler
raise errorclass(errorvalue)
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: not enough arguments for format string

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am using python 3.6, any idea of the ?

**UPDATE:**
This issue is resolved:

I use

```
cursor.executemany()
```

for this and its work.

Comment: Please fix code formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that each row read from the csv file is returned as a list of strings for `csv.reader`, you have to convert the list `row` to tuple, change your code to:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO noticias(title, \
link, pubDate )' \
'VALUES("%s", "%s", "%s")',
tuple(row))
```

**Update:**

Make sure there is table `noticias` in your mysql db, for example:

```
create table noticias (title Varchar(255),link varchar(255),pubDate varchar(255))
```

your `cnn.csv` file contains empty line, when read it, there will be empty list, you have to drop it, change your for loop like this:

```
for row in csv_data:
    if len(row)!=0:
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO noticias(title, link, pubDate ) VALUES("%s", "%s", "%s")',tuple(row))
```